# How should I use IOC container with dependencies which uses other dependencies?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently refactoring my code for the validation of Google Play In App Purchases for the backend of my App and I'm not sure what's the best solution for the initialization of the classes provided by the Google SDK.

The SDK from Google I'm using: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

For the validation I'm using this composer package: https://github.com/aporat/store-receipt-validator

My previous code for this:

```php
class GooglePlayIAPService extends InAppPurchaseService
{
    public function __construct(UserService $userService)
    {
        parent::__construct($userService);

        $googleClient = new \Google_Client();
        $googleClient->setScopes([\Google_Service_AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER]);
        $googleClient->setApplicationName('My app name');
        $googleClient->setAuthConfig(config('app.iap_service_credentials.google'));

        $googleAndroidPublisher = new \Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($googleClient);

        $this->googleValidator = new \ReceiptValidator\GooglePlay\Validator($googleAndroidPublisher);
    }


    /* The validation functions... */

}
```

I want to replace the *new* calls with calls to the IOC container, but my problem here is that the `Google_Service_AndroidPublisher` needs an initialized instance of `Google_Client`.
My approach was to use `App::makeWith(...)`, but I'm not quite happy with this solution...

```php
class GooglePlayIAPService extends InAppPurchaseService
{
    public function __construct(UserService $userService, Google_Client $googleClient)
    {
        parent::__construct($userService);

        $googleClient->setScopes([\Google_Service_AndroidPublisher::ANDROIDPUBLISHER]);
        $googleClient->setApplicationName('My app name');
        $googleClient->setAuthConfig(config('app.iap_service_credentials.google'));

        $googleAndroidPublisher = App::makeWith(Google_Service_AndroidPublisher::class, ['googleClient' => $googleClient]);

        $this->googleValidator = App::makeWith(GoogleValidator::class, ['googleServiceAndroidPublisher' => $googleAndroidPublisher]);
    }


    /* Validation functions */
}
```

Or maybe another approach would be to initialized the `Google_Client` completely in the `AppServiceProvider` but this would result in a loss of flexibility...

So my Question is:
Is there another good solution for this, which also allows easy mocking and testing?

Comment: Why don't you register all three services in your app provider and only inject the validator where you need it?

Comment: Cause of the loss in flexibility. What if I want to use an other application name for instance

Comment: That's a bit of an issue if you cannot replace it at runtime (I've no experience with this particular SDK). But you could also register multiple instances with different settings for example.